# Scrutinizer can't find .jshintrc

Tags: github, jshint, scrutinizer

I'm trying out tools for opensource projects, like travis and scrutinizer. In my root folder of github project I have both .jshintrc and .scrutinizer.yml. But, when I enable jshint tool in scrutinizer config file it reports that

```
Can't find config file: /.jshintrc
```

My repository: https://github.com/Misiur/Jawan

Did anybody encounter this error earlier?

Comment: This thread http://discourse.roots.io/t/error-cant-find-config-file-jshintrc/351 says "you just need to make sure the file .jshintrc584 is in the theme's root directory." Is your repo considered the "theme's root directory"?

Comment: I'm not using discourse, this is plain node.js module. .jshintrc is present in the root folder of the project.

Comment: Ok, just checking. But scrutinizer doesn't consider that folder as the theme's root folder apparently.

Answer (score 1):

Hm, this was a bit tricky, but it seems there were some changes in scrutinizer config.

You have to access scrutinizer -> your respository -> settings -> tick the "inherit" checkbox

OR

Add "inherit": true in your .scrutinizer.yml.

It seems there are four levels of configuration per check: checkout configuration (triggered by specific commit message), configuration for this specific inspection, repository configuration (.scrutinizer.yml in your repository), and global configuration for your whole SC account.